# SELECT FROM and INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I'm working on a script, but it won't work.
When a user makes a post, NOW() will be inserted. I want to make a script where the user will only be able to make a post when his last post differs at least 10 minutes from the post he wants to make at this moment. I don't want to make use of cookies, seeing people can delete them.

I have this code at the moment, but don't know how to move on. Thank you!

```
if ($db_found) {
    $sql1="SELECT send_time FROM bloopp WHERE email='$email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $last_post = $row['send_time'];
    }
    if ($last_post + 600 >= NOW() {
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO bloopp (bloopp, browser, medium, send_time, email) VALUES
           ('$bloopp', '$browser', 'desktop', NOW(), '$email')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result) {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else {
            echo "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On login take his last post with a left join, after he posts replace the content in the session...there you go

Comment: @KA_lin Do I need to make a left join, because it is all the same table? I'm not very familiar with joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with time, it's handy if you can rely entirely on the database. This avoids mixing up the database conception of time with PHP's, which may be on different servers and/or have different time configuations.

So, try to locate a post made in the last ten minutes, and if there isn't one, you know you are good to go

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS recent_posts
FROM bloopp 
WHERE email=? AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(send_time))<600;
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. :) I have two questions: where do I have to place this and why did you make use of count(*)?

Comment: You execute this query to find out how many posts they made in last ten minutes - if zero, you are free to make a new post. Your code is looping around a result set, which is unnecessary. This query always returns a single row.

Answer (score 0):

on the query you have :

```
 sql2 = "INSERT INTO bloopp (bloopp, browser, medium, send_time, email) VALUES ('$bloopp', '$browser',    'desktop', NOW(), '$email')";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

shouldn;t that be

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO bloopp (bloopp, browser, medium, send_time, email) VALUES ('$bloopp', '$browser',    'desktop', NOW(), '$email')";
```

mind the sql2 / $sql replacement

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have table user

```
user_table:
id
email

bloop:
email
browser 
....

Select * from user_table left join ( select max(send_time),email from bloop where email=$email ) max_sel on max_sel.email = user_table.email...
```

Something like this will get the user with his latest post (or null for new users who do not have a post, check put left joins), put the date in session and when he posts update it and such, you know how to do this.

Regards

Comment: So this code will replace everything above? But a session will expire when the browser is closed or am I wrong? :)

Comment: Yes it will expire but you would have to log him back in...using this suggested query (change the WHERE clause). It is a concept, you must adapt it a bit

Comment: But if it expires and the user closes the browser and comes back before 10 minutes, he will be able to post something again?

Comment: If he comes back before 10 min after he logs in you have his last post date in the session you can make the button grey or an alert message to tell him

Comment: Don't I have to set a cookie then?

Comment: Okay. And how do I insert the post then? With the code I already had?